# Azure - Active Directory in Virtual Network

Tags: azure, active-directory, vpn

The Goal : Move all AD services to a Server 2012 R2 virtual machine inside Azure.

**Why** The majority of my employees and contractors work from home or in the field, all around the nation. Our office only supports two people working full time as resource management.

**What we have done** Setup a 2012 R2 server with the AD role and DNS. Setup a Azure Virtual Network, and tied in the mobile systems and office systems via VPN. The server is on 10.10.80.1 inside the virtual network.

**What we expect to do** To help protect information and assets, our resources should be able to login via the domain hosted by the AD/DNS server in the virtual network, this would control desktop settings, etc as needed for our always mobile resources.

**What is actually happening** All units are pinging back and talking. I can see the AD server when I ping 10.10.80.1 with an outstanding response time. However, when I change the systems from WORKGROUP to a DOMAIN, I get the standard issue error that the Active Directory Domain Controller couldn't be found.

Now by all that I understand about AD, the DNS is there, and the AD is in fact online. So why are we having issues here? Any advice or fixes would be so helpful. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing as a test and I'm hitting the same problem: once I connect via the Azure VPN, I can ping it but I can't join the domain.

Comment: If it helps the problem is due to local machines not using the DNS on Azure (I'm don't know how to make that work). So what I did was setup a local DNS (I used SimpleDNS), added the DNS entries for my domain and the different SRV entries found on the Azure DNS (the ones that begin with "_"). I made the machine I wanted to join the domain to use this local DNS (which was handing as SimpleDNS allowed me to see what DNS calls where made and failed). In the end I got the machine into the domain successfully.

Comment: It sounds interesting.  Would you please get in touch with me, I may spend time with you to figure it out.

Comment: I have found an easier way. The Azure VPN seems a bit basic so I installed EtherVNP on the Azure server and on the machine I wanted to join the network. Just make sure you use the same subnet for both the Azure server and the local machine (EtherVPN add a network device that you can edit TCP/IP settings unlike the Azure VPN).

Answer (score 1):

Your on-premise gateway may be blocking the ports necessary for AD access from on-prem devices to AD in Azure (I'm assuming based on what you've written this is what you are aiming to achieve).  Here is a list of ports: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772723(v=ws.10).aspx.

If your gateway's not blocking ports it might be due to settings on your firewall device - take a look at the content here around MTU and RPC settings: http://blog.kloud.com.au/2012/07/25/windows-azure-virtual-network-vpn-with-tmg-2010/

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Azure BizTalk Hybrid Connection, we had to perform similar action, to access on-premise resources from Azure, I hope you find this one useful:

I believe you can use Azure BizTalk Service, to setup a secure connection to your on-premise resources, including SQL Server, Active Directory and etc.

This way will have several benefits as once the connection is set, you can code like you are connecting to an on-premise resource: 
More Info :

1. **[MSDN: BizTalk Services](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/biztalk-services/)**
2. **[Introduction to Azure BizTalk Hybrid Connection on](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEgNE_-KC90)**